# duplicating a value inside array with using a value in another array PHP

Tags: php

hi i have three array like this

```
$arr1 = array(2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4);
$arr3 = array();
```

i need a loop function to duplicate each of the value inside $arr2 with the value inside $arr1 so the end result should look like this:

```
$arr3= array(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4);
```

i know that i need to do an array_push into the $arr3 with $arr2[i] by doing this

```
for($i=0;$i < count($arr2);$++){
 array_push($arr3,$arr2[$i]);
}
```

but i dont know the outer loop for iterating the array_push loop, what should i add to do the duplicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1:*** You need to apply a `foreach()` and `for()` loop

1.Iterate over the first array `$arr1`

2.Check that value with the same key of the first array exists or not in the second array

3.Apply a loop based on first array values

4.Assign same value repeatedly based on loop

```
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$arr){

  if(isset($arr2[$key])){

     for($i=0;$i<$arr;$i++){

      $arr3[] = $arr2[$key];

     }
  }
}

print_r($arr3);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1005648

***Solution 2:*** You can use `array_merge()` and `array_fill()`

```
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$arr){

  $arr3= array_merge($arr3,array_fill(count($arr3),$arr,$arr2[$key]));

}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($arr3);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1005666